# How can we save a file of any type from an InputStream using Kotlin for Android?

Tags: android, file, kotlin, inputstream, storage-access-framework

**Context:**

My project is in the space of WiFi P2P/ WiFi Direct. I have found and followed some useful tutorials and questions and have a working app for sending Images between phones.
A socket is opened and an OutputStream sent to the other device. Device 2 receives the stream and has to assume the mime Type in order to compress and save to a file.*

EDIT: *Only has to compress for images, but needs to know the File type to save it to storage.

I would now like to open up this feature to transfer a file of any (common) type and have the other device happily receive it and stash it in the appropriate location (Or just all to Downloads might make it simpler).

**My question:**

What can I use to determine the MIME type for all (image, text, calendar events, contacts, videos) files coming in as an InputStream.

**Current code attempts:**

I have tried using *BitmapFactory.decodeStream()* to receive options and mimeType. This only works for Images.

*guessContentTypeFromStream()* hasn't worked at all and I think it might only be suitable for streaming from internet source?

Any clarifications/tips on how Storage access framework should be used here, or techniques to determine mimeType are appreciated!

Below is code used on the Receive side:

```
inner class RxClass: Thread() {
    lateinit var socket: Socket
    lateinit var serverSocket: ServerSocket

    override fun run() {
        try {
            serverSocket = ServerSocket(8888)
            socket = serverSocket.accept()
            //If this line is reached, then a connection has been established between server and client
            Log.d("RECEIVE", "Connection established")

            lateinit var bitmap: Bitmap
            lateinit var inputStream: InputStream
            lateinit var outputStream: OutputStream
            var mimeType: String? = null
            lateinit var path: String

            try {
                inputStream = socket.getInputStream()
                Log.d("RECEIVE", "got InputStream")
                runOnUiThread { Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Receiving file...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
                //mimeType = guessContentTypeFromStream(inputStream)

                val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options)!! //TODO: this needs to be for all file types
                mimeType = options.outMimeType
                Log.d("RECEIVE", "Decoded input, Type: $mimeType")
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            when(mimeType){ //I was hoping that my attempt would let me know what MIME type was and then here I can act on it differently if neccessary
                "image/jpeg" -> path = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
                "image/jpg" -> path = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
                "image/bmp" -> path = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
                "image/gif" -> path = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
                "image/png" -> path = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES

                "audio/mpeg" -> path = Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC
                "audio/x-wav" -> path = Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC

                "video/wav" -> path = Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES
                "video/mp4" -> path = Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES

                "text/plain" -> path = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS
                "text/html" -> path = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS
                "text/x-vcard" -> path = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS
                "text/x-vcalendar" -> path = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS

                null -> Log.d("RECEIVE", "MIMETYPE is NULL")
            }
            Log.d("RECEIVE", "Save file in location: $path")
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                val resolver: ContentResolver = contentResolver
                val contentValues = ContentValues()
                //contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
                //contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, mimeType)
                //contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, path)

                val rxUri: Uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)!!
                val inputStream = socket.getInputStream()
                outputStream = resolver.openOutputStream(rxUri)!!
                Log.d("RECEIVE", "Sending File: $rxUri")
                inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)

                if(bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream)) {
                    runOnUiThread { Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "File Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
                }
                Log.d("RECEIVE", "close streams")
                outputStream.flush()
                outputStream.close()
                inputStream.close()

                runOnUiThread {
                    ReceivedImage.setImageURI(rxUri)
                }

            } else { //Version less than Android Q is not implemented
                
            }
        } catch (e: IOException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

**Useful links**

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#add-item

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/BitmapFactory

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Device 2 receives the stream and has to assume the mime Type in order to compress and save to a file.` No. If it knows a name it can just write the received bytes to a file output stream. No need to compress anything. Would you compress a pdf file? You dont need an intermediate bitmap to send an image file. Just wasted code and runtime.

Comment: "What can I use to determine the MIME type for all (image, text, calendar events, contacts, videos) files coming in as an InputStream" -- the sender should positively tell you what the MIME type is, the way a Web server tells the Web browser what the MIME type is.